# Nonsensical edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits

[user1974711](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1974711/user1974711?tab=activity) has made several edits to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306557/find-occurances) which make the question nonsense because it removes all the code which tries to illustrate the issue. Granted, the question is not great and has been closed anyway, but the edits absolutely do not help improve the question. When I rolledback the edits, <del>he/she made the edit again *and* someone approved it.</del> (My mistake. The OP rolledback my rollback. The behavior of user1974711 is still suspicious.) What is the procedure dealing with this kind of behavior?

Comment: You saw this too, eh?  I'm really not sure what to make of it.  Even a high-rep user made a nonsensical edit, so I'm suspecting puppetry here.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention

Comment: @Bart I sent off a flag over an hour ago.  Not much doing about that post yet.

Comment: @Makoto After a closer look, I see that the OP rolled back my rollback. It certainly doesn't do anything to improve the question, so I'm not sure about this motivation.

Comment: I noticed that the OP was doing that as well.  It doesn't improve the question or help their cause whatsoever...

Comment: I think the OP wants to delete the question.

Comment: @nhahtdh That's very probable.

Comment: @Bart I flagged it. I guess it's in the moderator's hands now and I can move on to help someone who really wants help.

Comment: @Code-Guru Yeah, I flagged it as well. That should get their attention, if the continuous rollbacks didn't already trigger something. Let's see.

Comment: @Bart: It has appeared in the 10k mod tool.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to: [Question with 60 revisions without real change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160461/182513)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Definitely looks like similar behavior as described in that link.

Comment: Aaaaaand, the post is gone. I guess the OP got what he wanted, but it's always a shame for those who were kind enough to help and put in some free effort.

Comment: @Bart but at least there is enough attention that if something nefarious was going on, the mods will deal with the OP.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Oh sure, that will be handled I'm sure. P.s. we should use the word "nefarious" more often. It's a great word.

Answer (score 4):

Flag the question and move on. That's what I did when I saw that question, after making [one quixotic attempt at a rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14306557/19). Raise a custom flag, and describe the vandalism.

The OP probably posted their homework verbatim, realized that that might get them in trouble, and wants to hide the evidence. Since there's an upvoted answer on the question, the OP is [prevented from simply deleting the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/delete-past-questions-with-accepted-answer-or-more-upvotes), and they decided to vandalize its content instead. A moderator will probably either delete the question, lock it from further edits, and/or suspend the OP.

And yeah, there's some funny business going on with those suggested edits.

Comment: The edits are OP-approved, so they can get approved ignoring all other reviews. They are clearly the same person.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yeah, but if they're the same person, why bother making a suggested edit at all? The OP can do that with their original account.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Rep-gaming perhaps?

Comment: He did it twice, and got roll-backed, so maybe he thought someone else editing his post would look more convincing.