# Allow anonymization of posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-user, anonymous, ownership

I wanted to post a response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772340/what-is-the-worst-programming-job-you-ever-had-and-why), but I don't want it to show up in my list of answers (not only because I don't want it associated with my careers account, but also I don't want it associated with me *at all*). It would be nice if I could check this while submitting my post:

[ x ] Post anonymously (no reputation will be earned; post will not appear in your list of questions/answers)

...which would make the post be owned by the Community user, so that it is truly anonymous.  If this option were available when editing a post (like "make community wiki" is), it could be used to anonymize earlier posts as well, without needing to involve a moderator.

Comment: i agree... they wont do it though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said

Comment: Look, we all already know about your time in a Siberian circus.  It's nothing to be ashamed of, really.  The good news is that most employers admire a candidate who has experience scooping up elephant dung, as it's eerily similar to most corporate jobs.  Your time as the beared lady, however, is trickier to spin.  Just put down "intern," that's close enough.

Comment: @Pesto: I see you're taking your latest name change quite seriously indeed!

Comment: Hilarious Comedy Pesto is **Hilarious**!

Comment: I am displeased with the downvotes knocking me below 3000. *Thoroughly* displeased. ;)

Comment: @Pesto: What's a "beared lady"? Or will I regret asking the question?

Comment: It's a bearded lady without the 'd' for discretion.

Comment: +1 sympathy upvote. Ding!

Comment: @Adam: You just violated like 14 million meta unspoken rules.

Comment: Meta? rules? surely you jest.

Comment: @Æther: Rule #1, do **not** post anything controversial on Meta when you're near a rep/power threshhold. ;-)

Comment: @mmyers: A "beared lady" is a lot like a "mmyers," except it knows better than to point out my typos.  Also, it's not a jerk.

Comment: This is META!!!!!

Comment: @Pesto: What's a "mmyers"? I've never figured that one out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Log out and make the post anonymously.

Comment: That would work, but it feels like a crude workaround. We are capable of being more elegant about it. :)

Comment: It may feel like a crude workaround, but how often does it come up?  Is it worth the time to design, implement, and test it, or would that time be better spent on some other problem where there is no workaround?

Comment: This truly ... is the answer.

Comment: You cannot post questions on sites anonymously.

Comment: @Calmarius If you log out, then the only thing you need to provide to post a question is an email address - something that is easily obtained anonymously - so yes, you can post questions anonymously.

Answer (score 3):

Either you log out and post anonymously, or don't answer the question.

If you don't want people finding something, don't do it, it's the safest way

Comment: mindless sheep, all of you

Answer (score 3):

That isn't the best of questions to use as a basis for such a feature request... whether the referenced question belongs on SO at all is, I think, open to differences of opinion.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer.