# Anonymous questions

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should there be an option to post anonymously?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79390/should-there-be-an-option-to-post-anonymously)
>   [Need to ask a question anonymously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/need-to-ask-a-question-anonymously)
>   [Ability to ask questions anonymously but still get notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136422/ability-to-ask-questions-anonymously-but-still-get-notifications)

On traditional Stack-Exchange sites, such as Stack Overflow and many others, there is probably little rationale for people to want to remain anonymous. However, on sites such as workplace and academia, for many questions, it might be essential anonymous, due to the nature of the question.

How can the Stack Exchange network accommodate this need, given the system of reputation?

This is similar to this question: [Allow registered users to hide username when asking privacy-sensitive question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130534/allow-registered-users-to-hide-username-when-asking-privacy-sensitive-question?lq=1) but I take it a bit broader, discussion on general strategies etc...

Comment: Or this: [Need to ask a question anonymously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/need-to-ask-a-question-anonymously)

Comment: Or this: [Ability to ask questions anonymously but still get notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136422/ability-to-ask-questions-anonymously-but-still-get-notifications)

Comment: Or this: [Allow anonymization of posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31741/allow-anonymization-of-posts)

Comment: Unless you know the user personally outside of the site - everything here is anonymous... Gravatar default images, default `user12345` usernames...

Essentially no one knows who you are outside of the network.  Are you talking about anonymity within the network?

Comment: Or this: [Allow registered users to hide username when asking privacy-sensitive question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130534/allow-registered-users-to-hide-username-when-asking-privacy-sensitive-question)

Comment: Ah crap...you already know about the last one...

Comment: @Lix that is only true for people who have, to this point, decided to keep their assigned username and default gravatar. For me, since I have used my real name from the start, it would be very hard for me to ask an "anonymous" question without creating a second account (or using Oded's solution and simply asking an anonymous question and tracking it manually).

Comment: Good work, @UristMcBobby.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Bwahaha...I need to do this more often with more questions.

Comment: @UristMcBobby yep, [all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132156/what-if-i-answer-a-question-that-i-know-is-correct-and-the-user-uses-but-doesnt#comment365379_132156) the [cool kids](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117338/can-there-be-a-badge-encouraging-answering-a-certain-ratio-of-questions#comment307360_117338) are [doing it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110966/should-we-allow-downvotes-on-meta-feature-requests-if-they-just-dont-like-the#comment287369_110966).

Answer (score 11):

You can always post an anonymous question. Log out and post it.

For such a question you will not get any rep - that's the price for anonymity.

What you are asking for is a way to ask a question anonymously and yet keep it linked to your account - I find the two mutually exclusive.

Comment: I have no idea why they would be. We're not talking about espionage here, the level of anonymity is fairly low; it's fine if the system itself knows who posted it, it just shouldn't show the user's name anywhere

Comment: Not on Stack Overflow you can't - you need to be a registered user to post questions

Comment: Am I missing something or is this just out of date? When I try to post a question without being logged into an account I get "You must be logged in to ask a question on Meta Stack Exchange". So it seems that most of this answer doesn't apply anymore.

Answer (score 7):

You can always try:

> ***A friend of mine*** has an embarrassing problem with foot odor. Whenever <strike>he</strike>she wears the same shoes for more than four hours, there is an overpowering stench. What should <strike>he</strike>she do?

YMMV, of course.

Comment: `"A friend of mine..."`  nudge...nudge...wink...wink

Comment: [That approach sounds oddly familiar...](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html)