# Posting anonymously - but with a catch

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties, anonymous

I have read through most if not all topics concerning *posting anonymously* on Meta, but I haven't find any satisfactory topic.

Some people argue that it is necessary to be able to post anonymously. I agree on that. The proposed answer to that is to log out and post as an *actual* anonymous user, as has been answered and commented multiple times (e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3721/optional-anonymity-to-hide-ignorance#answer-3725) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79390/should-there-be-an-option-to-post-anonymously#answer-79391)) . **This, however, is not what I would think is the more logical option.**

Sometimes it is preferable to ask a question anonymously:

- You don't want to be associated with the question, but you really want to know the answer (questions concerning *sexuality* and others come to mind)
- [The answer is embarrassingly simple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3721/optional-anonymity-to-hide-ignorance)
- You are sure that because of your low rep you won't get enough feedback
- [You don't want to link a question to your account, which is linked to your Careers account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31741/allow-anonymization-of-posts)

A solution would be to allow an option which posts your question as *anonymous*, but which is still linked to your account. A possible extension could be allowing anonymous bounties. This means that:

- you will still get **notifications** through the normal notification menu
- your anonymous questions (and bounties) will still be **stacked with your "normal" questions on your profile**, but the anonymous ones *will only be visible to you*

The downside of this for the poster would be that he **cannot gain any reputation** by asking anonymous questions - as to provide transparency where a user got his rep - but questions can be up or downvoted (to make clear whether a question is relevant/useful).

Also, please be so kind as to elaborate on why you decide to downvote.

Comment: And maybe an option to 'de-anonymise' if the resulting answers and discussion is something you do want to be associated with after all.

Comment: "You are sure that because of your low rep you won't get enough feedback" What?

Comment: If *you* think (I don't) you won't get good feedback because of low rep, surely posting anonymously would be worse?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Not necessarily, because no one will know the reason why you posted anonymously.

Comment: @BramVanroy: I think his point was "If people don't pay attention to low rep users, why should they pay attention to anonymous users (which are even a step below beginners)".

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby I would not know why they should be "below" low rep users. If the usage of the anonymous function is used frequently (a lot of users might use it now and then) it does not need to get a bad connotation.

Comment: @BramVanroy: You said that you might get not enough attention based n your reputation...by that logic people with more rep get more attention, people with less get less attention and people *without* any rep (anonymous users) get the least.

Comment: @BramVanroy regarding your edit downvotes are different on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @Rory I know, but it helps when people explain why they disagree.

Comment: I would definitely love to see that "post as anonymous" feature implemented.

Answer (score 6):

I see no need for this whatsoever. None of the scenarios you describe shows to me that there is a need for such a feature

> You don't want to be associated with the question, but you really want to know the answer (questions concerning sexuality and others come to mind)

If you don't want this associated to your account, start a new account. There is nothing preventing you from having a separate account purely for a single site in the network. Heck, you could theoretically even have multiple accounts on a single site, as long are you don't get involved in fraudulent behaviour.

> The answer is embarrassingly simple

So? Just ask it. Even the brightest minds get stuck on a trivial thing every now and then. And if it's really so simple that it doesn't make a good question to begin with, do your own research.

> You are sure that because of your low rep you won't get enough feedback

Now that would require some evidence. Seeing the SO game at work on a daily basis, I don't see any evidence for this happening. You might not get enough feedback if your question is bad. But a low-rep user with a good question will certainly get feedback.

Posting anonymously would, as I imagine, only hurt in this case. We have users bring up here on Meta that they really don't like answering questions from users with a userXXXX name. That doesn't give me a lot of confidence for anonymous users.

> You don't want to link a question to your account, which is linked to your Careers account

That pretty much falls under what I have said to your first point. But say you have already asked something you no longer wish to be associated to you. Guess what? You can already ask for that content to be disassociated, [which SO/SE has to comply with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said/26851#26851). There is no magic button for you to do so, but all you have to do is ask.

So all in all I see no need for anonymous posting, given the options already available to you.

Comment: One of the major points in my post is the idea of keeping all information in one place. When having multiple accounts, you'll have to log into another account.

Comment: That's the (minor) price you'll have to pay for wanting to be anonymous. Keep in mind that you're asking developers to make (possibly quite significant) changes to a system for something that is of limited use and already covered by existing functionality.