# How can I close and permanently (for forever) remove my own question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean)
>   [There needs to be a way to delete content or disassociate your account from said content.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said)

As in title: how can I obliterate a question that I've previously asked?

Comment: Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your own question, but only as long as it doesn't have too many answers or answer upvotes.

This is to prevent question owners from removing quality answers along with their questions.

See:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/

Answer (score 0):

You should have a delete link under your question, click on it to delete it.

[alt text http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/262/uploadcm.png](http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/262/uploadcm.png)

Comment: The thing is that "deleted" content is still visible to users with 10k reputation and moderators, and is still associated with the author's account...

Comment: But this is only a to vote to delete.

Comment: @Jitendra - if it's your own question it will get deleted, no other votes are required.

Comment: Needs more freehand circles! :)

Comment: I suck at free hand drawing, was waiting ( knew, going by MSO track record) somebody would fix it :P

Comment: everybody sucks at freehand drawing with-a-mouse, that's the whole point...