# When a user deletes his/her post from Stack Overflow, is it completely removed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

When a user deletes his/her post from SO, is it completely removed?

I think the post should remain in SO.  Users generally remove their downvoted questions and answers to save their reputations, but a deleted post might be a genuine answer with a good solution, or a good question; thus, it should not be deleted from SO entirely.

The post should remain on SO without any info about the user who asked it.  In this way, that post remains available for discussion.

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  Instead of deleting answers, offer the option to disassociate it from your account.

Comment: @jinguy That would encourage spam.

Comment: @devin, that wouldn't *encourage* spam, but it would make it easier.

Comment: @devinb that's why we have Spam flags.

Comment: @Jjnguy Yes, quite true, but I prefer fear-mongering to rational response.

Comment: Is this really necessary?  How often are the actual correct answers not only downvoted, but downvoted so hard that they cause a net loss of rep?

Comment: @MLO: there is a "vote as spam" option; they're the spam flags that @George referenced.  You can click "flag" under any post to access this feature.

Comment: @MLO, wait, I'm confused.  At first I thought you were talking about answers, since you said "might be genuine answer with the solution to a question"; but you also say "The question should remain on SO."  Are you asking about answers, questions or both?

Comment: possible duplicate of [There needs to be a way to delete content or disassociate your account from said content.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said)

Comment: Question and answer both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the question is just marked as "deleted". 10k users can still view it and vote to undelete it.

Also, normal users cannot directly delete questions with voted-up answers.

Comment: Regarding the second paragraph, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51192/why-was-the-question-owner-able-to-delete-their-own-question-testing-question