# Privacy settings in question belongs to me

Tags: discussion, privacy

I have asked some questions which is private for me so I never want to give my username to  my co-workers. Is there a solution for this? At least can I make them invisible from my profile?

Comment: You might want to vote for [There needs to be a way to delete content or disassociate your account from said content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said).

Comment: I don't understand why you don't simply withhold your username from your co-workers in the first place. There's no technical involvement needed, that way. Also why you're posting things to the Internet that you consider "private"; there's an inherent contradiction there.

Comment: I have no rights to ask private questions on here or anywhere on internet ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

All questions are publicly linked to your profile.

You *could* post them as an unregistered (and hence anonymous) user, but remember to keep bookmarks to the questions so you can find them later. However, this could be construed as sock-puppetry.

I'm not advocating that you do that and if you do decide to go that route, **don't** engage in any voting with this new account and **don't** vote up it's questions with your registered account.

Comment: This is quite sad for me that i have to pass new account just for this problem :(.

Comment: Once something is posted to the web it's **forever**.

Comment: It seems more sad to me that your coworkers apparently don't understand you don't know everything, @Freshblood.

Comment: @Arjan - Problem is not about hiding my technical knowledge from anyone. Think that you are asking a questions about problems which you encounter in current job or about previous bad job experiences.That's what i want to disassociate it from my account.