# Where can I read about "name removed"?

Tags: discussion, display-names

Today I've noticed for the first time various questions/answers/comments on various SE sites with "name removed" instead the asker's/answerer's/commenter's name?

What are the reasons for this? Do you ask for it while posting or after posting? Or does somebody else decide this?

Is there somewhere in the documentation I can read about it. Searching with Google and within SE didn't lead to anything.

Comment: Do you have examples?

Comment: @ChrisF: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/415/should-questions-regarding-public-perception-of-skeptic-issues-be-allowed

Comment: As a minor side note, the [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) license under which we operate **requires** that we provide a means of removing attribution. Section 4(a): *"If You create a Collection, upon notice from any Licensor You must, to the extent practicable, remove from the Collection any credit as required by Section 4(c), as requested."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a blue moon some Stack Exchange contributors would wish to disassociate or delete the posts that they have done. Since the content is community owned, an option provided to them is to anonymize the contributions that they have done.

Such an arrangement allows for content to be retained, as well as give the OP the option of a post no longer being attached to them.

Due to the request of disassociation, it's highly unlikely you will find more about the person - unless they have explicitly posted elsewhere & has been been indexed by the Search Engines

> Is there somewhere in the documentation I can read about it?

Some previous answers on this:

- [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/can-i-delete-my-account)
- [There needs to be a way to delete content or disassociate your account from said content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said/26851#26851)

Comment: @hippietrail updated.