# Is there a way to make one of my questions private and not visible from my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

Is there a way to make a question or answer I post not visible in my profile?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @MartijnPieters for privacy reasons.

Comment: If you accidentally entered personal information, the only way to permanently delete is to have the Team do it

Comment: Of course, the very best solution is to not post sensitive material in the first place.  Once you post something on the InterWebz, it tends to stay out there more or less permanently, in places like Google and the Wayback Machine.  We can't do anything about those sites.

Comment: Ummm...no.  No there is not.  And for good reason.

Comment: Related: [There needs to be a way to delete content or disassociate your account from said content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't make a question or an answer private ***and*** keep it linked to your account. We have no plans to implement anything like that at the moment.

However, you [can completely disassociate yourself from a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa).

(And of course, as others have said, be careful when posting sensitive information in the first place.)

Comment: This needs to be publicized waaay better, I've been an SO user for nearly a decade and only just found this out. Occasionally users publish sensitive stuff under their own names and need to fix that quickly before Google archives it forever.

Comment: Does "linked to your account" automatically mean "visible in my profile"?

Comment: @pmor It does, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You could delete the question or the answer and it would no longer be visible to anyone except 10k+.

Unless you really no longer want this to be available and or helpful to anyone, then I don't know why you would want to do that.

EDIT:
Or as stated in the comments you can [have the post disassociated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa) from your account.

Comment: I want the question and/or answer to remain on the site, I just don't want it listed on my profile

Comment: if you ask the question it is associated with you. Deleting is the only way to remove it but it removes it from the site all together.  Why wouldn't you want it on your profile?

Comment: i am very active on a particular stack where people know me, but i asked a very personal question on another stack where i'm completely unknown.

Comment: @asifahnik I don't show any other stack accounts associated with your profile here, are you using multiple accounts?

Comment: asking for a friend ;)

Comment: @asifahnik unless you delete it there is no way to remove it from a profile page. If you ask/answer it, there would be history that you owned it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create another account and do that. If you don't want to create a new mail adress, you can use multiple adress functionality: sing up using youremail+secret@youremailprovider.com.

Comment: Not all mail providers support the "+" notation, but yeah, that is solid advice.