# Similar Functionality as Facebook's 'Hide From Activity Feed'

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In my first question [here](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/multiple-stackexchange-accounts-for-anonimity), I brought up the idea of perhaps allowing users to selectively show/hide things from their profile page. I liken this to Facebook's 'Hide From Activity Feed' functionality.

The rational is pretty straightforward and subjective to each user. The bottom line is that we give the users more options for how they display what they've done on here.

It may be a bit hairy to implement but perhaps allowing a +/- (public/private) toggle next to each action would suffice.

Public view of a profile on SX:

[image]

Facebook feature to 'hide':

[image]

Comment: Personally, I can't see a need for this, as if you don't want to show something on your public profile, why not just not put it on your profile? If you want more eyes to see this post, I am happy to migrate it to meta.se, which is the meta site for all of stack exchange.

Comment: It actually might be better served there. Also, I was thinking more in terms of the things you cannot change on your profile page, like questions/answers. Let me add some screens and then you can migrate it please.

Comment: I hope it's ok, but I used a snip from your profile (I couldnt use mine unless I logged off -and lord knows that's too many clicks;)

Comment: Are you asking for a way to participate on a site but *hide the fact that you did so, selectively*?  That seems like a really bad idea to me.  Your Facebook space is yours to do with as you choose, but SE doesn't belong to you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this would make much sense. Everything you contribute to a Stack Exchange site is under the [CC licence](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) - as long as the information is attributed back to you anyone can do pretty much anything with it.

The fact that you choose to contribute to the site means that whatever appears on your profile was put there by you.

If you would prefer that a certain answer/question will not appear on your profile, you have two options:

1. Post it from a different account that is not directly associated with you.
2. (for existing content) Flag the post and ask a moderator to disassociate  your account from the post.

---

Related:

- [There needs to be a way to delete content or disassociate your account from said content](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said?answertab=votes#tab-top)