# Low-quality questions should be easier deletable by their OP

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts

There is nothing better than someone, who wants to maintain a high-value account.
In fact, many users do but there are are a few things that complicate that matter.

**I think that low-quality, low-value questions should be deletable almost exclusively, regardless of the presence or absence of answers.**
Question posters may have just asked the wrong question.
The inability to delete it, because of the presence of ANY sort of answers is just vile.

Sure, me being totally fine to get my answers deleted by the OP along with the question does not mean others would agree, but if you know that this may happen you will be free to decide on your own, whether to "invest your time and effort" in such a falling apart question. Putting your time and effort into low-quality questions have almost no contribution value to anyone.

The new changes regarding question upvote value suggest that question askers are found to be not less important than answer posters, but this also requires a look into their privileges respectively or the whole idea behind that is not what they say it is (or it is, but only partially - i.e it is rationalized).

Perhaps questions voted < 0 should be deletable by the OP.
Another purposed criterion is that the answers are not voted yet if the idea behind this is that radical.

How I would have done it?
If user wants to delete its question - fine. If there are answers to that question with reputation > 1 their author will get notified that the question OP wants to delete the question (reputation unaffected). When and if all answers with reputation > 1 get deleted, the question will get deleted automatically immediately after.
It is a balanced approach that keeps the social factor but also allows users to get rid of their old irrelevant low-quality bad reputation questions.

Comment: Curious to know why people don't agree
So leave a comment if possible.

Comment: "because of the presence of ANY sort of answers" - that's not quite right. The question can be deleted by the author as long as there are no more than one answer, and that answer doesn't have a positive score.

Comment: Alright yes, just not too sure about that answer count restriction. Also, the reason warning that appears when you try to delete undeletable question is inaccurate because the real reason would be that even though the question is bad, the answers have value. Nothing to do with investing time and effort. It's no reason.

Comment: The question author being unable to delete its own question, just because someone received 1 score or just because two people answered does not seem optimal to me.

Comment: `Curious to know why people don't agree` Suggesting that answers are disposable and should be sacrificed because the author of a question wants to delete a poorly received post (i.e LQ question), is "unappealing" to most users. Answers on VLQQs are somewhat rare, but if the content of answer is good and helps the OP, why should it be thrown out?

Answer (score 12):

We generally don't want answerer's efforts to be wasted.

On Stack Overflow, for example, we have a problem with users posting a question and then immediately deleting it after it received an answer - probably to avoid getting caught by their tutors. Sometimes they delete and repost their question if they didn't like the answer - sometimes they do that more than once.

Sometimes users even try to *force* other users to delete their answer so they can delete their question (see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391430/1288408) recent example). This would certainly get worse if your suggestion of notifying answerers would get implemented.

It's also not good to delete answered questions because an answer is not supposed to help the original poster alone, but other users having the same problem as well.

Lastly, it's better to improve questions that weren't well received than to delete them since deleting several downvoted questions can contribute to a question ban.

Comment: Thanks to the user who helped many people that way, he gets rewarded with account suspension.

Comment: @Edenia It is worse to delete a lot of downvoted questions. Their score still counts when it comes to suspensions.

Comment: Did not say behavior like this should be tolerated. it will exist in either case, but not if the users have the chance to delete their question easily and fairly. A force should not be necessary but in every country everywhere, people become that angry, because of the choices they dont have.

Comment: @Edenia Is this about a specific question? Maybe we can help with that. How was the question "wrong"? Asked on the wrong site?

Comment: Ah, no. I guess I am just a liberal person that sees a problem and tries to purpose a solution. This is a problem affecting the mindest of users. Editing the question rendering it completely irrelevant in order to try to force answerers to delete their question is a common practice.

Comment: @Edenia If you see that practice, please rollback or flag. Behaviour like that is not acceptable.

Comment: If one does care for the entire community as a whole he shouldn't neglect the user's decision to delete his question in a few other circumstances at least. The potential lost of value should be re-estimated.

Comment: Yes, flag it, but what will the moderator do exactly? Restore the original question and lock it?

Comment: @Edenia Users _can_ delete their questions if the conditions to do so are met. But as soon as a question has several upvoted answers the decision to delete does not only affect the original poster, but others and the community as well. That's why the original poster can't decide to delete on their own. It would be different if Stack Exchange sites would be personal help desks, but they aren't.

Comment: Damn right it affects others too. If this changes, then those who wish to post answer can step aside and think twice.

Comment: @Edenia Yes, if the behaviour continents, they would. The original question can (and should) even be restored by non-moderator users.

Comment: People will know their answers can get deleted with the question. They will just not answer such a question and save a lot of trouble or accept the risk.

Comment: @Edenia Please don't make this a problem of the answering users. As I said before, this is not only affecting bad questions. Even good questions get deleted when answered because users don't want to get caught by tutors or where asking during a competition or a test.

Comment: Stack Exchange has a very strong and very weak side. It is well-moderated, well-designed, useful, but too many people struggle with the criteria to make good questions, too many people rage quit, rage downvote and so on.

Comment: Yes, okay. I guess I will just have to admit that Stack Exchange have this Windows tendency. To deprive users of choice. At least you can earn it by the reputation-privilege system. So not that windows. If you think this affects the community positively, I just don't want to argue.

Comment: @Edenia Even for some LQ, low reseached questions there may be good answers, that may be helpful for future research. It doesn't help the OP anyways if they could easier delete their not so well received questions. As already stated these would still count for a possible quesiton ban.

Comment: @Edenia Yes, that's bad. But it often happens because they have wrong expectations and get disappointed when participating. SE's model might not be the right choice for every question. Maybe they can be asked better on other sites.

Comment: Then mods should not be able to delete answered with voted answers question as well.

Comment: @Edenia There's quite well a difference, if a mod or high-rep community members decide to delete a question or the OP does so.

Comment: @Edenia Take a look at this, it is possible to disassociate a question from your account: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26844/204841

Comment: Homework cheats deleting their question as soon as they get an answer is a big problem on several sites, not just Stack Overflow. It's probably worse on Mathematics.SE than it is on SO. It rarely happens on Physics.SE due to its very strict policy on homework-like questions.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the block on self deletions isn't just about low quality questions - there's also folks who ask questions and delete once they get an answer for various reasons.

Its also worth considering - while poor quality questions are undesirable, we'd rather folks consider their questions, rather than throwing whatever comes to mind on screen, and deleting once they get an answer.

Practically - the answers are not just there for the original question asker. They are also there for other people with the same issue. If your question can be improved, without negating the existing answers, it may be a good idea. Or simply to think about your questions first.

Comment: So the user does not get the chance to fix his mistake in cases he posts the wrong question? Earning from that mistake would be impossible too, because he may get suspended.

Comment: @Edenia The user can improve their question by editing it. Deleting downvoted questions is not a good solution - it can lead to a question ban.

Comment: Well - it takes a *pattern* of bad questions to get question banned. And "Wrong" question is an 'interesting' way to put it. Low quality can be improved. Low value is relative. You can sometimes actually find value in seemingly trivial things too. Fundamentally its about how best we can serve the commons

Comment: I'd also add *great* questions are difficult. I'm trying to work out how to ask one on my own site because it feels broad and trivial, yet its something I'd like to know about. That said, if I'm happy with it, it will be *epic*

Comment: can not be edited to be improved, because it is the "wrong" question. Means that editing it will most likely change the subject and invalidate other answers. And in the real world, some people just don't have the capacity to do it. If it really is a community then every opinion matters. Every user is important. You can't just always put others on the first line. It's controversial.

Comment: @Edenia No, every opinion does *not* matter. The goal of SE sites is to build & maintain a repository of knowledge. We can't expect every asker to become an ideal member of the community, but we *can* expect them to put in some effort to writing a useful question with long-term value. On SE sites you "pay" for good answers by writing good questions. If the OP needs help doing that, we can assist them to improve their question. But if they are simply too lazy or too selfish to write a good question we do not want their questions or their opinions.

Comment: @PM2Ring Then it is isn't a QA community it is a knowledge repository. Btw I lived long enough to know that the initial idea was not like this. I mean don't get me wrong, I am fully contempt with SE and its sites. I just see a mess of social factors and in the same time rationalized contradictory terms. And all that just greatly lacks transparency.

Comment: We don't care about people's opinions, people's problems, people in general, but the pop-up message that appears when you try to delete answered questions is about respecting people's time and effort. Nothing about actual value. And there is nobody to estimate if the answers actually do provide any value. Any placeholder question with 1 upvote can disable users to delete their LQ question or so I heard.

Comment: @Edenia I didn't say that we don't care about people's opinions. I said we don't care about *every* opinion. There's a big difference.

Comment: I know. Others have said it though.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the recent changes (balancing vote values for questions), the value of answers is much higher than questions.

The overall long term goal of the SE sites is to help not only the OP of a question, but being helpful for everyone who comes over a specific problem in future research (if I am not mistaken that didn't changed meanwhile).

---

> There is nothing better than someone, who wants to maintain a high-value account. In fact, many users do but there are are a few things that complicate that matter.

The OP may regain the rep points when deleting a question, but the downside is that these questions still count against a possible question ban.

Not to mention that the questioners are boldly warned to do so
(see **[READ EVERYTHING WE ARE ABOUT TO TELL YOU.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)**).

As it was mentioned before, it's generally better to encourage the OP to edit their questions.

---

Thus answered questions should be kept, no matter how low the corresponding questions score is. We're not here as a voluntary help center just for the question poster.

---

If ◆mods or high rep users (> 20k) decide to delete a question, that's a very different situation.
As these are trusted and have insight of how specific sites work, and the set up policies, they may delete questions to avoid endless and useless discussions about e.g. opinion based questions.

Comment: We aren't. But most users ask only for themselves. Unless they become serious SE users. I think they deserve a little more control over their downvoted questions with an overall lower value. It is actually going to improve things for everyone.

Comment: BT dubs I love greek music. I can trust you just from that you are greek haha. Smart people. .. but I still hold on my opinion :)

Comment: @Edenia _"But most users ask only for themselves."_ We don't care. At least even LQ questions can serve as good examples what not to do.

Comment: Oh well then. We can expect all that rage imminently.

Comment: @Edenia You'll be surprised that I am not from greece if you take a closer look at my profile :-D

Comment: Oups. Awkwaaaaard

Comment: @Edenia Well, at least I liked _Aphrodite's child_ a lot when I was young ;-)

Comment: @Edenia "But most users ask only for themselves" We don't want such users. We don't care and should not care if someone posted bad question and wants to get rid of it. It is their problem, they should think twice before posting a question.

Comment: @Her Thank you Dalija for backing up again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would probably add explanation why mods and high reputation users can delete questions even if there are upvoted answers.

Comment: @Her I tried a bit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I should have recognized that from the pre-twentieth century spelling, but calling me a beginner at Greek would be kind.

Comment: @rock It's just a bit of an attitude of mine ;-)