# Ability to ask questions anonymously but still get notifications

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, anonymous

For some of the sites, such as security, parenting and the workplace, it would be useful to be able to ask questions anonymously. For example, someone might want to ask about issues that could either lead to a security compromise, be embarrassing for their children later on or possibly lose them their job.

On those sites it is possibly to log out ([not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/encouraging-users-to-create-an-account-and-keep-it/107163#107163) on Stack Overflow), but this doesn't provide you with notifications when the questions are answered.

**Related questions:**

[Should there be an option to post anonymously?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79390/should-there-be-an-option-to-post-anonymously) Asks for the same feature, but for answers
[Should there be anonymous answers (and questions)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/should-there-be-anonymous-answers-and-questions?rq=1) Asks about this for a different reason

Comment: Could you explain why you think it would be useful?  Maybe it would, maybe it wouldn't - although pseudonyms are a form of anonymity in and of themselves.

Comment: @Makoto I think this might be useful, as many people share their SE account names with their co-workers, thus eliminating the anonymity.

Comment: How hard is it to keep an eye on the site?

Comment: Do anonymous accounts not receive notifications?

Comment: Some SE sites, like Personal Finance or Workplace, could really use this option.  Sometimes it's just not a good idea to post even an honest question that can be traced back to one's SE profile and possibly their real identity.  For example, if someone is asking about bankruptcy or problems with their boss.  Besides the fact that it's not obvious to the user that logging out will enable them to post anonymously, doing so would also prevent update notifications and seeing the question in the user's own Q&A history, both of which would seem to be core features of the SE sites.

Comment: +1: I've made another account on at least one occasion to post anonymously and still receive notifications etc.

Comment: I just tried logging out to post anonymously, but it won't let because it says that my email address is already registered.  This feature would be easy to implement; it sucks there is so little interest in developing it.

Comment: Marking the question as favorite (star, bookmark) provides a notification in the list of favorites. It's not in the main navbar, and it adds up with other marked questions, but it's still a notification...

Answer (score 5):

For embarrassing posts, you can "follow" your question (or answer) after posting from a throwaway account. You'll be able to get inbox notifications (but not rep notifications — not that it should matter).

For admitting to doing something really illegal, I would suggest not posting at all. But maybe you have more appetite for risk.

Note: You definitely don't want to use bookmarks as those are publicly visible in your profile and can be queried in SEDE.