# Possibility to ask anonymous questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, anonymous

The Stack Exchange network has been growing a lot in the past couple of years. By now there are many sites that are about potentially sensitive topics. One that comes to mind is https://workplace.stackexchange.com or https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com

I've seen many questions on those sites that probably should be asked anonymously (as in "not traceable to the real person"). Now some users, including me, prefer to go by their real name. We are virtually unable to ask those kinds of questions. Even if you anonymize your account for a certain site, you are still traceable due to your overall profile. I guess many of those users have a second account for such things.

I think a nice feature would be the possibility to ask a single question anonymously. I imagine a feature like this:

- You can mark a question/answer as anonymous when posting
- Question/Answer is not traceable to your account by other users. This has to go both ways (from viewing the post or your profile). Maybe it appears in your profile anonymized to display reputation and badges.
- From your view the question/answer is still linked to your account as you are used to.
- You will still receive reputation for those posts, if possible even badges. I realize this introduces the possibility to trace the question back to the user by metadata. But I doubt that it would be feasible in practice (You'd have to look through every user looking for the one with the matching reputation points gain).
- Possibly marking past posts as anonymous (would enable a anonymous user to shift to real name)
- Maybe making the feature configurable per site. I guess there is not much need to ask anonymously e.g. at Stack Overflow.
- Bonus feature: If you already have a second anonymous account you can migrate it to your "main account".

As I'm a developer myself, I realize this is a very complex feature for a relatively small subset of users. But perhaps more users would go by their real name if such a possibility exists. Also it might also proof useful to pseudonymous users because you might be able to connect them to the real person in some way.

What do you think?

---

Very much related, but, IMHO, not a 100% duplicate:

- *[Ability to ask questions anonymously but still get notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136422/ability-to-ask-questions-anonymously-but-still-get-notifications)*
- *[Need to ask a question anonymously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/need-to-ask-a-question-anonymously)*
- *[Solution for semi-anonymous posts / accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172951/solution-for-semi-anonymous-posts-accounts)*

Comment: If you're concerned with you privacy it is much easier if that is handled by each individual instead of having to add complexity that is only for the benefit of a few users. There are also all kind of pitfalls like: what do you do with badges that you earn for a post while you marked it as anonymous? That would still blow your cover if they are awarded.

Comment: Related: [Solution for semi-anonymous posts / accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172951/solution-for-semi-anonymous-posts-accounts).

Comment: @rene You have valid concerns I failed to adress. See my edit. Also I agree that this might not be fully conceived. It is an idea I tried to throw in the ring.

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it too. If you want the reputation to flow to your account, you can't ask "anonymously". If you _really_ want to ask anonymously, use a different email address. If the question (or answer) is important enough to you, imaginary internet points don't matter.

Answer (score 3):

> The Stack Exchange network has been growing a lot in the past couple
>   of years. By now there are many sites that are about potentially
>   sensitive topics.

Per site you can obfuscate the information, as you can hide your community, and rename your profile per community. ([How do I hide my accounts on a specific Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290092/how-do-i-hide-my-accounts-on-a-specific-stack-exchange-site) or [Hiding sites from the main StackExchange.com profile page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267121/hiding-sites-from-the-main-stackexchange-com-profile-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

That way you are anonymous on that site you want to post anonymous thing on, unless someone find you with a SEDE request. It protect at least from job hunter that can google your name and/or your profile name.

Actually, I see a lot of users that do that on MSE.

Comment: It's very easy for a snooper to figure out who's account it is using SEDE.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog oh, didn't knew that part, thanks for the information, so it's more you can obfuscate the info then. edited to be more acccurate

Comment: I wasn't aware of that feature. How do questions appear on a site which I have hidden? Are they still posted with mit (site specific) user name? And what happens if someone clicks on it to open my profile?

Comment: @AndréStannek They only see your site specific info, but as Sonic's told, I wasn't aware of, is you can discover who it's by using SEDE, as such it's not completely anonymous. As I knew some users that hided their sites as they contribute on religious's site, to not impact their main profile